# SQL: I need advice on how best to accomplish a complicated query

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a complicated query that I need to produce for a report. The query gives me what I need, but takes about 5 mins to run. For a report, this isn't acceptable, so I want to dump these results into a table via an overnight job and truncate the table before it runs each time. Where I'm running into trouble is how best to accomplish this, given how the query is structured, so I was hoping to get input on how I might do this. I'll break the query down as best I can into a mile-high view below:

```
CREATE TABLE #SALESDATA
(
...
)

INSERT INTO #SALESDATA
EXEC STAGING_DATA_PROC

WITH CTE1 AS 
(
PRELIMINARY DATA 1
JOINED WITH #SALESDATA
),

CTE2 AS
(
PRELIMINARY DATA 2
JOINED WITH #SALESDATA
)
```

So what I first attempted to do is tried to circumvent the STAGING_DATA_PROC by just making it a query in its place, but it itself contains a few INSERTS into temp tables and doesn't seem to like the nesting of inserts in that order.

Any insight into how I might go about this?

---

**UPDATE 1:** This is the SQL that is taking about 5 mins to run. I have since replaced my SP feeding a temp table to a stand alone table that gives results instantly.

```
with basedata as (
select distinct a.order_num
        ,a.Period_Date
        ,a.year as std_the_year
        ,a.Month as std_the_month
        ,a.customer as std_StandardAcctNo
        ,b.salesperson
        ,isnull(ac.counter,0) [Appearance_Count]
        ,isnull(b.[Year],0) [The_Year]
        ,isnull(b.[Month],0) [The_Month]
        ,isnull(b.customer,0) [CustomerName]
        ,sum(isnull(b.Gallons,0)) [Gallon_Qty]
        ,sum(isnull(b.sales,0)) [Total_Sale]
        ,sum(isnull(b.gm,0)) [Total_Gross_Profit]
from (select distinct a.year
                ,a.month
                ,b.customer
                ,convert(integer,convert(varchar(4),a.Year) + right('00' + convert(varchar(2),a.month),2)) as order_num
                ,convert(date,convert(varchar(2),a.Month) + '/01/' + convert(varchar(4),a.Year)) as Period_Date
        from IdealElephantSalesData a
    join (select distinct customer from IdealElephantSalesData) b on 1 = 1
        ) a
        join RicoCustom..Appearance_Count ac on a.customer = ac.customer_alias
    left join IdealElephantSalesData b on a.customer = b.customer and a.Month = b.Month and a.Year = b.Year
group by a.order_num
        ,a.Period_Date
        ,a.year
        ,a.Month
        ,a.customer
        ,b.salesperson
        ,ac.counter
        ,b.[Year]
        ,b.[Month]
        ,b.customer
)

, saleslist as (
select distinct salesperson
                ,Appearance_Count
                ,Period_Date
                ,std_the_month
                ,std_the_year
                ,std_StandardAcctNo
                ,isnull(sum(Total_Gross_Profit),0) Period_GP
from basedata
group by salesperson, Appearance_Count, Period_Date, std_StandardAcctNo,std_the_month,std_the_year

), core_GP as (
select distinct a.customer
                ,convert(date,convert(varchar(2),a.month) + '/01/' + convert(varchar(4),a.year)) as Period_Date
                ,sum(a.gm) as Period_GP
from IdealElephantSalesData a
join RicoCustom..Appearance_Count ac on ac.customer_alias = a.customer
group by counter, convert(date,convert(varchar(2),a.month) + '/01/' + convert(varchar(4),a.year)), a.customer


), GroupedData AS ( 
   SELECT distinct cgp.std_StandardAcctNo, cgp.Period_Date, sum(cgp.[Total_Gross_Profit]) as Period_GP, Appearance_Count
   FROM basedata cgp
   group by cgp.std_StandardAcctNo, cgp.Period_Date, Appearance_Count

), GP_Grouping as (
select std_StandardAcctNo
        ,min(Period_Date) as range_start
     ,max(Period_Date) as range_end
     ,count(*) as range_count
     ,GP_group
from (
      select std_StandardAcctNo, Period_Date, case when Period_GP = 0 then 0 else 1 end as GP_Group
            ,row_number() over (PARTITION BY std_StandardAcctNo, case when Period_GP = 0 then 0 else 1 end order by Period_Date) as rn
            ,row_number() over (PARTITION BY std_StandardAcctNo, case when Period_GP = 0 then 0 else 1 end order by Period_Date) - row_number() over (PARTITION BY std_StandardAcctNo order by Period_Date) as grp
            ,row_number() over (PARTITION BY std_StandardAcctNo order by Period_Date) as grp2
      from   GroupedData
     ) a
group by std_StandardAcctNo, grp, GP_Group
),GP_Group2 as (
select gd.*, max(gpg_prev.range_end) as last_zero_group 
FROM GroupedData gd
left join GP_Grouping gpg on gd.std_StandardAcctNo = gpg.std_StandardAcctNo and gd.Period_Date between gpg.range_start and gpg.range_end
left join (select * from GP_Grouping where GP_Group = 0 and range_count >= 12) gpg_prev on gpg_prev.std_StandardAcctNo = gd.std_StandardAcctNo and gpg.range_start >  gpg_prev.range_end

group by gd.std_StandardAcctNo, Period_Date, Period_GP, Appearance_Count, gpg.range_count 

), GP_Group3 as (
SELECT gd.*
   ,Appearance_Cnt_Rel = case when gd.last_zero_group is null then Appearance_Count else ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY gd.std_StandardAcctNo, gd.last_zero_group ORDER BY gd.Period_Date) end

FROM GP_Group2 gd

), almost_done as (

select distinct bd.order_num
        ,bd.Period_Date
        ,bd.std_the_year
        ,bd.std_the_month
        ,bd.std_StandardAcctNo
        ,case when bd.[Appearance_Count] > 0 then bd.[Appearance_Count]
                when isnull(c.Appearance_Count,0) > 0 then c.Appearance_Count + 1
                when isnull(d.Appearance_Count,0) > 0 then d.Appearance_Count + 2
                when isnull(e.Appearance_Count,0) > 0 then e.Appearance_Count + 3
                else 0
                end as Appearance_Count
        ,bd.[The_Year]
        ,bd.[The_Month]
        ,bd.[CustomerName]
        ,bd.[Gallon_Qty]
        ,bd.[Total_Sale]
        ,isnull(c.Appearance_Count,0) as Prev_Count
        ,isnull(d.Appearance_Count,0) as month2_Count
        ,isnull(e.Appearance_Count,0) as month3_Count
        ,case when bd.salesperson is not null then bd.salesperson 
            when c.salesperson is not null then c.salesperson
            when d.salesperson is not null then d.salesperson
            when e.salesperson is not null then e.salesperson 
            else 'NA' end [SalesPerson]
        ,case when bd.[Appearance_Count] is null and c.[Appearance_Count] is null and d.[Appearance_Count] is null then e.Period_GP else 0 end [Lost_Gross_Profit]
        ,case when bd.Appearance_Count = 1 then bd.Total_Gross_Profit else 0 end as 'New_Cust_GP'
        ,case when bd.Appearance_Count <= 12 then bd.Total_Gross_Profit else 0 end as 'Young_Cust_GP'
        ,case when bd.Appearance_Count > 12 then bd.Total_Gross_Profit else 0 end as 'Old_Cust_GP'
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bd.std_StandardAcctNo, bd.std_The_Year, bd.std_The_Month ORDER BY (bd.std_StandardAcctNo) DESC) as UNI_Period
        ,bd.Total_Gross_Profit as SalesP_GP
        ,isnull(cg.Period_gp,0) as Period_gp
        ,case when isnull(b_prev.Period_gp,0) > 0 then isnull(b_prev.Period_gp,0)
                when isnull(d.Period_gp,0) > 0 then isnull(d.Period_gp,0)
                when isnull(e.Period_gp,0) > 0 then isnull(e.Period_gp,0)
                else 0 end as Prev_Period_GP
        ,h.Mat_MoM_Shift
        ,case when isnull(b_prev.Period_gp,0) > 0 then isnull(b_prev.Period_gp,0)
                when isnull(d.Period_gp,0) > 0 then isnull(d.Period_gp,0)
                when isnull(e.Period_gp,0) > 0 then isnull(e.Period_gp,0)
                else 0 end * h.Mat_MoM_Shift as Expected_GP
        ,isnull(c.Period_gp,0) as True_Prev_GP
        ,isnull(d.Period_gp,0) as True_2month_GP
        ,isnull(e.Period_gp,0) as True_3month_GP
        ,ideal_candidate = case when ((isnull(c.Period_gp,0) + isnull(d.Period_gp,0) + isnull(bd.Total_Gross_Profit,0)) / 3 >= 800) and isnull(c.Period_gp,0) >= 150 and isnull(d.Period_gp,0) >= 150 and isnull(bd.Total_Gross_Profit,0) >= 150 then 'Y' else 'N' end
        ,eleph_candidate = case when ((isnull(c.Period_gp,0) + isnull(d.Period_gp,0) + isnull(bd.Total_Gross_Profit,0)) / 3 >= 5000) and isnull(c.Period_gp,0) >= 1000 and isnull(d.Period_gp,0) >= 1000 and isnull(bd.Total_Gross_Profit,0) >= 1000 then 'Y' else 'N' end

from basedata bd
    left join core_GP b_prev on bd.std_StandardAcctNo = b_prev.customer and b_prev.Period_Date  = dateadd(month,-1,bd.Period_Date)
    left join saleslist c on c.std_StandardAcctNo = bd.std_StandardAcctNo and c.Period_Date = dateadd(month,-1,bd.Period_Date) and case when bd.salesperson is not null then bd.salesperson else c.salesperson end = c.salesperson
    left join saleslist d on d.std_StandardAcctNo = bd.std_StandardAcctNo and d.Period_Date = dateadd(month,-2,bd.Period_Date) and case when bd.salesperson is not null then bd.salesperson when c.salesperson is not null then c.salesperson else d.salesperson end = d.salesperson
    left join saleslist e on e.std_StandardAcctNo = bd.std_StandardAcctNo and e.Period_Date = dateadd(month,-3,bd.Period_Date) and case when bd.salesperson is not null then bd.salesperson when c.salesperson is not null then c.salesperson when d.salesperson is not null then d.salesperson else e.salesperson end = e.salesperson
    left join RicoCustom.dbo.[Rico_Global_Monthly] h on h.month = bd.std_the_month
    left join core_GP cg on bd.std_StandardAcctNo = cg.customer and cg.Period_Date  = bd.Period_Date


),get_ideal as (
select distinct min(ad.Period_Date) as ideal_Period_Date
        ,ad.std_StandardAcctNo
        ,rc.last_zero_group
        from almost_done ad
        left join GP_Group3 rc on rc.Period_Date = ad.Period_Date and rc.std_StandardAcctNo = ad.std_StandardAcctNo and rc.Period_GP = ad.Period_gp
        where ideal_candidate = 'Y' and (rc.Appearance_Cnt_Rel between 3 and 6) 
        group by ad.std_StandardAcctNo,rc.last_zero_group
), get_elephant as (
select distinct min(ad.Period_Date) as eleph_Period_Date
        ,ad.std_StandardAcctNo
        ,rc.last_zero_group
        from almost_done ad
        left join GP_Group3 rc on rc.Period_Date = ad.Period_Date and rc.std_StandardAcctNo = ad.std_StandardAcctNo and rc.Period_GP = ad.Period_gp
        where eleph_candidate = 'Y' and (rc.Appearance_Cnt_Rel between 3 and 36) 
        group by ad.std_StandardAcctNo,rc.last_zero_group
)
select rc.Appearance_Cnt_Rel
        ,gi.ideal_Period_Date
        ,ge.eleph_Period_Date
        ,ad.*
    from almost_done ad
    left join GP_Group3 rc on rc.Period_Date = ad.Period_Date and rc.std_StandardAcctNo = ad.std_StandardAcctNo and rc.Period_GP = ad.Period_gp
    left join get_ideal gi on ad.std_StandardAcctNo = gi.std_StandardAcctNo and ad.Period_Date = gi.ideal_Period_Date
    left join get_elephant ge on ad.std_StandardAcctNo = ge.std_StandardAcctNo and ad.Period_Date = ge.eleph_Period_Date
where order_num > 201001 


GO
```

Comment: This is a big step for optimization -- are you sure your query can't be optimized via indexes?  I'd also suggest a Materialized View instead of an ETL maintained table, if you can implement it that way -- which you can if your insert is only a single select.

Comment: I think I may have just thought of a solution. Instead of using the SP, create a job to populate a table with that SP, then instead of joining on the temp table, I can join on that real table, allowing me to make this whole thing a SP.

Comment: But I don't think there's room for indexes, given how it's done. The materialized view is a good idea, I will probably try that if my other plan fails.

Comment: Not sure you mean that you can't nest SPs. You absolutely can call a stored procedure from within a stored procedure. And even a temp table generated in the outer procedure is visible within the nested procedure...although this is not really a good idea. Unfortunately your request for help is so extremely vague nobody can really do much to help you.

Comment: There is always room for indexes -- this is how SQL systems work well.  Please explain more why you think there is no room -- or give us the SQL that is running slow so we can tell you how to make it faster.

Comment: Sean - Thank you for pointing that out, I mis-typed. I meant it was my inserts that cannot be nested.

Comment: What's that `JOIN` 1=1 for?  Wouldn't it create a cartesian product of the 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried breaking your complicated query into smaller queries that load the data into temporary tables.  You can use the temporary tables to build your final result.  With the temporary tables, you can build the necessary indexes against them to ensure better performance.  Additionally, you will be working with smaller subsets of the data which should result in better performance.